# Query on use of aggregate functions over recursive groups in microsoft report designer

Tags: recursion, aggregate, rdlc

I have to point out that I'm fairly new to reporting outside of Microsoft Access, and new to the site, so please bear with me!

Stripped down to essential items, my data object has:
CategoryID, ParentCategoryID, TransactionID, TransactionDate, SplitID, CurrencyID and Value.

I don't think this is relevant, but just in case -

- A Split has a Category and a Value, with one to many belonging to a Transaction.
- Multiple Splits may exist for the same Category & Transaction with
  different, or the same, Value (to support different combinations of the other data
  items I haven't listed).
- A Transaction has a TransactionDate and a CurrencyID, so all Splits
  belonging to a Transaction are for the same Currency.
- A Category belongs to a Category recursively.

A Split may be assigned a Category at any level in the recursive hierarchy and the crux of my problem is to report Transaction / Split detail under the appropriate Category heading, with a sub-total to include all those details AND the totals of all child Categories.

So, I have a Detail row group holding all the ancilliary data items that aren't relevant and a TransactionIDGroup row group on the same row. I then have a CategoryGroup row group based on CategoryID with a Parent of ParentCategoryID to handle the recursive nature of the data and a CurrencyIDGroup column group to handle the possible multiple currencies involved.

Also in the CategoryIDGroup row group is a total row with the Value cell holding an expression.

If I leave that expression as =Sum(Fields!AccountValue.Value), the report quite nicely totals the Value for each Currency column for all the details specifically in each Category (the default scope), so I thought I needed to make the Sum 'Recursive'. However, you don't seem able to specify the optional Recursive parameter without specifying the scope as well.

If I specify scope as CategoryIDGroup, I get all zero sub-totals. If I use CurrencyIDGroup I get each one being the same report total for the Currency. Anything else either gets me a build error or a combined-currency report total.

The other issue I have is that the recursive child Category groups are reported sequentially underneath the parent Category group (so, outside the header row, detail rows and total row, and not within the group. However, if I can get the total to reflect the children as well as the details at that level, I'd be happy enough, even though it wouldn't seem to add up until you realised what was going on.

What I have in mind is something like:

```
Category A
Transaction 1 10/02/2011   ......................    £100.00
                           ----------------------     £14.50
Transaction 2 18/03/2011   ......................               $159.34

   Category Ai
Transaction 3 18/06/2011   ----------------------    £295.60
   Total Category Ai                                 £295.60
Total Category A                                     £410.10    $159.34*
```

But what I get is this:

```
Category A
Transaction 1 10/02/2011   ......................    £100.00
                           ----------------------     £14.50
Transaction 2 18/03/2011   ......................               $159.34
Total Category A                                     £114.50    $159.34*

   Category Ai
Transaction 3 18/06/2011   ----------------------    £295.60
   Total Category Ai                                 £295.60
```

I guess the fundamental question is - am I asking the impossible? Do I need to take a different approach, perhaps with sub-reports for the details? I've wondered about including a Sum of the values of the child Categories within the data object at each Category level, but is there something simple I'm missing?

Any pointers in the right direction would be greatly appreciated after several days tearing my hair out :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea whether there was something simple I missed, but resolved the issue to my satisfaction by including another property in the data object, being the sum of all child categories for each currency, and including a new row to print the sum of that field. Just in case someone else hits just the same question!